# How to implement a follow and unfollow system on multiple user IDs being displayed in a single component at the state level in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I will like to implement a follow and unfollow system that's base on objects IDS in the state. Like for example if a user.id is already in the arrays of users IDS in the state show unfollow button else show follow button.
All being implemented on a single user component follow button not affecting the rest of the user's follow or unfollow button.

Here's my code for a better understanding of the question:

Thanks in advance for your help, which I will really appreciate.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native'

const users = [
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    username: 'Jerry'
},
{
    id: 2,
    user_id: 2,
    username: 'Peter'
},
{
    id: 3,
    user_id: 3,
    username: 'Sumo'
},
{
    id: 4,
    user_id: 4,
    username: 'Musu'
}]
export default function TestingScreen() {
let initialState = [
    {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        username: 'Jerry'
    }
  ]

const [followingList, setFollowingList] = useState(initialState);
const ids = followingList.map((following) => following.id);
alert(JSON.stringify(followingList));
 return (
    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }}>
    {users.map((user, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{user.id}</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{user.username}</Text>

            {user.user_id !== ids ? 
            <Pressable 
            style={{
                fontSize: 20, 
                backgroundColor: 'black', 
                padding: 10
            }}
            onPress={()=> setFollowingList(current => [...current, {id: user.id, username: user.username}])}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>Follow</Text>
            </Pressable>
            :
            <Pressable
            onPress={() => 
                setFollowingList((current) => 
                current.filter((followingList) => followingList.id !== user.id))
            }>
            
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Unfollow</Text>
            </Pressable>
            }
        </View>
    ))}
</View>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `includes`

```
{!ids.includes(user.user_id) ? ...
```

Also, wrap this with useMemo

```
const ids = useMemo(() => followingList.map((following) => following.id), [followingList])
```